# Counting new distinct values of a certain column for each value of a date column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with four columns, looking like this:

```
id,name, key, date
 1,'A' ,'x1','2015-11-11'
 2,'A' ,'x1','2015-11-11'
 3,'B' ,'x2','2015-11-11'
 4,'B' ,'x2','2015-11-11'
 5,'A' ,'x1','2015-11-12'
 6,'A' ,'x1','2015-11-12'
 7,'B' ,'x2','2015-11-12'
 8,'B' ,'x2','2015-11-12'
 9,'D' ,'x3','2015-11-12'
```

I want to count the number of distinct *new* `key`-s for each `date`:

```
2015-11-11  2                     -- (two distinct keys: x1 and x2)
2015-11-12  1                     -- (one new key: x3)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(key) AS keys
FROM (
  SELECT DATE, key, LEAD(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS new
  FROM (SELECT DATE, key FROM YourTable GROUP BY DATE, key)
) WHERE new IS NULL
GROUP BY DATE 
ORDER BY DATE
```

Below version preserves dates even if there is no new keys detected.
Just wrapper around first answer

```
SELECT dates.date AS DATE, IFNULL(CAST(keys AS INTEGER), 0) AS keys
FROM (
  SELECT DATE, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(key) AS keys
  FROM (
    SELECT DATE, key, LEAD(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS new
    FROM (SELECT DATE, key FROM YourTable GROUP BY DATE, key
    )
  )
  WHERE new IS NULL
  GROUP BY DATE
) AS counts
RIGHT JOIN EACH (SELECT DATE FROM YourTable GROUP BY DATE) AS dates 
ON dates.date = counts.date
ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want if date 2015-11-12 don't have new key x3 then show 2015-11-12 is 0. How to do this?

Comment: I just changed my question, please help me new case. Thank sir so much!

Comment: mixing/changing question makes it unclear and hard to answer. I recommend you to create new question and I will be glad to take a look and try to answer new one

Comment: I'm so sorry. Thank you for your advice! I make new question and rollback this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750048/counting-distinct-values-of-a-certain-column-for-each-value-of-a-date-column-and

Comment: can you help me this case?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823840/query-distinct-in-google-bigquery