# Counting distinct values of a certain column for each value of a date column and 3 key

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with four columns, looking like this:

```
id,name, key1, key2, key3, date
 1,'A' ,'x1','y1','z1','2015-11-11'
 2,'A' ,'x1','y2','z1','2015-11-11'
 3,'B' ,'x1','y2','z1','2015-11-11'
 4,'B' ,'x1','y1','z2','2015-11-11'
 5,'A' ,'x1','y1','z1','2015-11-12'
 6,'A' ,'x1','y2','z3','2015-11-12'
 7,'B' ,'x2','y3','z3','2015-11-12'
 8,'B' ,'x2','y1','z4','2015-11-12'
 9,'D' ,'x2','y1','z4','2015-11-12'
```

I want to count the number of distinct *new* `key1, key2, key3`-s for each `date`:

```
2015-11-11  3                     -- (two distinct key1, key2, key3 row 2,3)
2015-11-12  3                     -- (new key and distinct key1, key2, key3)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your keys do not have | char inside them (pick another char if this is not a case:

```
SELECT DATE, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(key) AS keys
FROM (
  SELECT DATE, key, LEAD(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY key ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS new
  FROM (SELECT DATE, CONCAT(key1, '|', key2, '|', key3) AS key 
        FROM YourTable GROUP BY 1,2)
) WHERE new IS NULL
GROUP BY DATE 
ORDER BY DATE
```

As you can notice this is just slight adoptation of my answer to your previous question. I combined all three keys into one  - and applied exact same code as before