# How to mapping 2 table condition the first day

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 table with columns, looking like this:

Table A

```
key_a, date_a
 'k1', '2015-11-25'
 'k2', '2015-11-10'
 'k3', '2015-10-09'
```

Table B

```
id, key_b, date_b
 1, 'k1',  '2015-10-01'
 2, 'k1',  '2015-11-02'
 3, 'k1',  '2015-11-25'
 4, 'k2',  '2015-10-15'
 5, 'k2',  '2015-11-09'
 6, 'k3',  '2015-09-15'
 7, 'k3',  '2015-10-02'
 8, 'k3',  '2015-10-08'
```

I want to find row in table B have `date_b` is first with same `key_b`:

```
key_a, date_a,       id, date_b 
 'k1', '2015-11-25', 1,  2015-10-01
 'k2', '2015-11-10', 5,  2015-11-09
 'k3', '2015-10-09', 6,  2015-09-15
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick one  - should work

```
SELECT
  key_a, date_a, b.id AS id, b.date_b AS date_b
FROM table_a AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    id, key_b, date_b,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key_b ORDER BY date_b) AS num
  FROM table_b
) AS b
ON a.key_a = b.key_b
WHERE b.num = 1
```

Comment: One more condition for this question. Can you help me?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083801/mapping-2-table-with-between-date-for-each-row